# How to create a hello world DNN module from scratch

Tags: dotnetnuke, web-frontend

I've been looking for tutorials on making modules for DNN, and all of them seem to suggest starting from a huge template and then adding what you need to it, but I'm sure there is a way to build a very small, lightweight module with just the barebones. Just use an ASCX view, and show it on the screen. What is the simplest hand-written `"Hello World"` DNN module? If you really do need a whole lot of extra stuff in a module for it to work, what is the cleanest way to get a module template?

Background: I've come from front-end development, and I'm looking for a way to package my front-end scripts and styles together, then just use a single file as an AJAX endpoint to query to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your DNN version, there is an easy way to create a simple module within DNN itself.

When you go to "Host > Extensions", there is a button with something like "Create new module". Fill out the fields and it will create a module for you that you can use like any other.

When the module is added to a page you can edit the source code (C# / VB) in the module itself.

This is the fastest way to create a basic module. But I would still recommend the template from [Chris Hammond](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates). It is slightly more complex but will be easier to maintain and can be packaged as a standalone installer for other DNN installations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with that.

Comment: I approve this message